# addition at the left of number

Tags: c++, c

How we can we do addition at the left FF instead 00?
For example we have a = E8, we need a = 0xFFFFFFe8

```
 0xFFE26C02 -> 0xFFE26C02
 0x000000e8 -> 0xFFFFFFe8
 0x100000e8 -> 0x100000e8
 0x001000e8 -> 0xFF1000e8
```

P.S. data type int32 or int64

Comment: Those calculations don't look consistent to me.

Comment: which data structure? int or string?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit where is contradiction? I don't see

Comment: @Dipto int 4 bytes ot 8 bytes

Comment: @Qwerty: In the left-most byte you have `0x10`->`0x10` but `0x00`->`0xFF`. Then in your second example the entire first three bytes takes on `0xFF`. Is it just me, or does that make no sense?

Comment: Do you mean "turn leading 00's into FF's, until you hit a non- '00' byte?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean replacing left zeros (which nothing means) with 0xFF

Comment: @jimmcnamara yes exactly!

Comment: What would `0x01111111` result in?

Comment: @alk 0x01111111 -> 0x01111111 because 1st byte = 01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to convert all leading bytes of `0` to `FF`

```
int RevLeadingZeros(int number)
{
    if((number & 0xFF000000)==0)
        number |= 0xFF000000
    else
        return number;
    if((number & 0x00FF0000)==0)
        number |= 0x00FF0000
    else
        return number;
    if((number & 0x0000FF00)==0)
        number |= 0x0000FF00
    else
        return number;
    if((number & 0x000000FF)==0)
        number |= 0x000000FF
    else
        return number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is how put the **bits left to the leftmost '1'** in the number?

Here is my solution:

Let's take the number 01001000( as num ) for example:

1. First, do ~num and you get 10110111.
2. Then plus 1, and the answer of (~num+1) is 10111000.
3. Do (~num+1) & (num), and you get 00001000.

So in the end, the result of the (~num+1) & num is to get the rightmost '1' in the num.

To get the left most one, do a loop, and the condition is:

```
while(num-(~num+1)&num)
```

In the end, you will get the number 01000000.

So it'll be easy to locate the '0' right to the leftmost '1'.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Without direct calculation, you can just iterate each byte of your integer and replace the last consecutive `00` with `FF`.

You can also `OR` your integer with a mask which can easily be built with a first traversing of your integer memory.